# R remove variable after assign() using paste0()

Tags: r

I need to create a variable using `assign()` to give it a dynamic name.
I later need to remove the variable.

```
day_no <- 1
df <- data.frame( a = 1:3, b = 4:6 )
assign( paste0( 'newdf_' ,day_no ), df )
```

This works fine.

The trouble is removing the variable afterwards.
I have tried:

```
rm( paste0( 'newdf_', day_no ) )
```

Or:

```
rm( parse( paste0( 'newdf_', day_no ) ) )
```

However I get this error message:

```
Error in rm(parse(paste0("newdf_", day_no))) : 
... must contain names or character strings
```

I have searched a lot online but cannot find the answer, some help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

For non-interactive use, use the `list` argument to pass your character name(s).

```
rm(list = paste0("newdf_", day_no))
```